# Getting RTF data out of Mac OS X pasteboard (clipboard)

Tags: macos, applescript, rtf, pasteboard

According to the `man` page for `pbpaste`,

```
   -Prefer {txt | rtf | ps}
          tells pbpaste what type of data to look for  in  the  pasteboard
          first.   As stated above, pbpaste normally looks first for plain
          text data; however,  by  specifying  -Prefer  ps  you  can  tell
          pbpaste to look first for Encapsulated PostScript.  If you spec-
          ify -Prefer rtf, pbpaste looks first for Rich Text  format.   In
          any  case,  pbpaste looks for the other formats if the preferred
          one is not found.  The txt option replaces the deprecated  ascii
          option,  which continues to function as before.  Both indicate a
          preference for plain text.
```

However (in my experience with 10.6 Snow Leopard at least), `pbpaste -Prefer rtf` never, ever gives up the RTF data even when it exists on the pasteboard. Is there any other simple way to get the RTF text of whatever’s ready to be pasted?

I tried AppleScript, but `osascript -e 'the clipboard as «class RTF »'` gives the response `«data RTF 7B`ton of Hex encoded crap`7D»`. Can AppleScript convert this hexdata into text I can play with?

Comment: A decade later, I went with this [swift solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36109230/676195). Worked great for html at least.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can't see any way to do it from inside AppleScript, but since you're working in the shell anyway, I'd just post-process it: the "hex-encoded crap" is the RTF data you want.  The simplest script I can think of is

```
perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack("C*",pack("H*",substr($_,11,-3)))'
```

An explanation: `substr($_,11,-3)` strips off the `«data RTF` and `»\n` bits (each of the guillemets is two bytes); `pack("H*", ...)` packs hex-encoded data into a bytestream; `unpack("C*", ...)` unpacks a bytestream into an array of character values; `print chr foreach ...` converts each integer in the array to its corresponding character and prints it; and the `-ne` options evaluate the script given for each line, with that line implicitly stored in `$_`.  (If you want that script in its own file, just make sure the shebang line is `#!/usr/bin/perl -ne`.)  Then, running

```
osascript -e 'the clipboard as «class RTF »' | \
  perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack("C*",pack("H*",substr($_,11,-3)))'
```

will give you raw RTF output.

Comment: Clever approach. Slight simplification is to replace `«class RTF »` with mere string `"RTF "` (note the required trailing space before the closing delimiter in either case): `osascript -e 'the clipboard as "RTF "' | perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack("C*",pack("H*",substr($_,11,-3)))'` - works on (at least) 10.8+. Also note that - by design - the AppleScript command will report an error if there's no RTF data on the clipboard.

Comment: I've added this really handy alias to my `.profile`: `alias pbpaste-rtf="osascript -e 'the clipboard as \"RTF \"'| perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack(\"C*\", pack(\"H*\", substr(\$_,11,-3)))'"`.

Answer (score 15):

I think that at least on OS X 10.8 this would work if you copied HTML content from Chrome:

```
osascript -e 'the clipboard as "HTML"'|perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack("C*",pack("H*",substr($_,11,-3)))'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy via AppleScript  (tested in 10.11 El Capitan):

```
set the clipboard to (the clipboard as «class RTF »)
```

---

You can create a Service via Automator:

1. open Automator
2. make new service ("Dienst" in German)
3. add "execute a AppleScript"
4. input: nothing; output; replaces Selection

The Script:

```
-- name: convert to RTF
on run {input, parameters}
    set the clipboard to (the clipboard as «class RTF »)
    return the clipboard
end run
```

Done. Now save the new Service and to try it out: Select a text, then go to the Application Menu and choose "Services" > "convert to RTF"

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's impossible to get RTF data out of `pbpaste`, even if the man page says otherwise.

The simplest solution is to use [pbv](https://github.com/chbrown/macos-pasteboard) instead, which was developed exactly to work around the limitations of `pbpaste`.

An example: after copying the following rich text string into your clipboard:

> "Hi, I'm **rich** *text*"

`pbv` is able to give you back proper RTF data:

```
$ pbv public.rtf | textutil -stdin -info
File:  stdin
  Type:  rich text format (RTF)
  Length:  19 characters
  Contents:  "Hi, I'm rich text"
```

Whereas `pbpaste` will always output plain text even when instructed to prefer RTF:

```
$ pbpaste -Prefer rtf | textutil -stdin -info
File:  stdin
  Type:  plain text
  Length:  19 characters
  Contents:  "Hi, I'm rich text"
```

Found via this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17217450/3078265).

Answer (score 1):

Plain AppleScript solution from me. It is faster than proposed in other answers:

```
-- script: Get raw RTF content from the clipboard
-- written: by me, right now

clipboard_as_raw_RTF()

on clipboard_as_raw_RTF()
    -- catch the hext text from the error message
    try
        (the clipboard as «class RTF ») as text
    on error errorMessage
        set hexRTFData to errorMessage
    end try
    -- clear the garbage text 
    set ATID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"«data RTF ", "»"}
    set hexRTFData to text item 2 of hexRTFData
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
    -- convert hexadecimal text to ASCII text
    do shell script "/bin/echo -n " & hexRTFData & " | xxd -r -p" without altering line endings
end clipboard_as_raw_RTF
```

And, here is interesting AsObjC solution from user @ionah on MacScripter. This code is even faster:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) or later
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions

on clipboard_as_raw_RTF()
    set thePasteboard to current application's NSPasteboard's generalPasteboard()
    set theData to (thePasteboard's dataForType:(current application's NSPasteboardTypeRTF))
    if (theData is missing value) then return theData -- If no RTF data.
    return (current application's NSString's alloc()'s initWithData:(theData) encoding:(current application's NSUTF8StringEncoding)) as text
end clipboard_as_raw_RTF

clipboard_as_raw_RTF()
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a [conversation](http://c-command.com/forums/showthread.php?t=366) about this with a quick google search

Comment: "However you will not be able to manipulate the RTF as a string within AppleScript.”

I saw that in my searches before I posted the question, but I find it unbelievable that there’s no way to get the RTF data out without writing to a file. (I want the RTF on STDOut, so I can make further changes to it.) Does anyone know enough AppleScript to know if this is true?

Comment: what is it that you want t do to the rtf data supposing that there a way to get the data ?

Comment: Convert it to HTML then convert the HTML to Markdown. Obviously, I could just write tempfile somewhere, but I’d really prefer not to for both performance reasons and aesthetic reasons. It seems like AppleScript should have a way to un-hex the data itself. Or that some other tool should exist for getting data off the pasteboard.