# How to get HTML data out of of the OS X pasteboard / clipboard?

Tags: macos, clipboard, pasteboard

I do have to send a report regarding pasting some clipboard content into a web rich editor and I need a way to dump/restore the clipboard content to (probably) HTML.

How can I do this?

It seems that pbcopy / pbpaste do alway give me text even if I use the `pbpaste -P rtf` or `pbpaste -P HTML`

Answer (score 23):

Three years later, in more civilized times, we have [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html). You can write a short Swift script to pull exactly what you need off of OS X's pasteboard.

Put the following Swift 4 snippet into a new text file. I named mine `pbpaste.swift`:

```swift
import Cocoa
let type = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.html
if let string = NSPasteboard.general.string(forType:type) {
  print(string)
}
else {
  print("Could not find string data of type '\(type)' on the system pasteboard")
  exit(1)
}
```

Then, copy some html, and run `swift pbpaste.swift` from the directory where you put that file.

Yay, html! Uggh, OS X added a ton of custom markup (and a `<meta>` tag?!) — but hey, at least it's not plain text!

Notes:

- `NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.html` is a special global that evaluates to the string `"public.html"`
- Obviously this is html specific, so you'd probably want to either:

  1. Name it `pbpaste-html.swift`, or
  2. Read the desired type from the command line arguments
- It's kind of slow, because it's being interpreted on the fly, not compiled and executed. Compilation gives me a 10x speed-up:

  ```bash
  xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc pbpaste.swift -o pbpaste-html
  ```

  Then just call `./pbpaste-html` instead of `swift pbpaste.swift`.

Comment: P.S. This basic approach evolved into a simple (but slightly more flexible — you can specify the data type as an argument) command line tool, published at https://github.com/chbrown/macos-pasteboard

Comment: For my needs I just added `#!/usr/bin/env swift` as the first line and made the file executable and it responds quick enough for me on my M1 Macbook.

Answer (score 15):

I realise you've already found this, but for the benefit of people who turn up here from Google, the solution given for RTF data at [Getting RTF data out of Mac OS X pasteboard (clipboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545289/getting-rtf-data-out-of-mac-os-x-pasteboard-clipboard) works fine for getting HTML out of the clipboard, too.

That is, the command

`osascript -e 'the clipboard as «class HTML»' | perl -ne 'print chr foreach unpack("C*",pack("H*",substr($_,11,-3)))'`