# How to get contents of the clipboard in the format of HTML on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, clipboard

I can get the contents of the clipboard in the format of HTML on linux by using `xclip`

```
xclip -selection clipboard -o -t text/html
```

How can I do the same thing on Mac OS X? I heard that I could use `pbpaste`, but none of the following command worked for me.

```
pbpaste
pbpaste -Prefer rtf
```

Sometimes it just output plain text, and sometimes it output nothing.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: See [this](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/OSX/cliphtml.html) (which is based on [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054952/how-to-get-contents-of-the-clipboard-in-the-format-of-html-on-mac-os-x)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get HTML data out of of the OS X pasteboard / clipboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217450/how-to-get-html-data-out-of-of-the-os-x-pasteboard-clipboard)