# Reading binary data from clipboard

Tags: python, macos, command-line, clipboard

I'm on a Mac, python 3.7.2.  I want to write text, linked to a url, to the clipboard.  This is so that I can paste it straight into a Wordpress site, an email, a Google doc, etc.

I copied a hyperlinked piece of text from a document and confirmed it works by pasting it into a different application.  The text retains its link to the specific url.

When I try and read that from the clipboard using `pbpaste` (in order to understand what bytes are needed to craft new hypertext linked strings I can put back onto the clip board) the text comes back as bytes but with no url present in it.  For example copying the following line:

[image: Line of text containing a hyperlink]

But on running the following code I don't see any URL information:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['pbpaste', 'r'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
stdout                                                                                                                      
b'This: 00:06 is a link to a video.'
```

It appears that's because `pbpaste` is loosing the extra information.  Is there any way to use this command line tool or any other python tool to get this rich text information from the clipboard?  Using `p = subprocess.Popen(['pbpaste', '-Prefer', 'rtf', 'r'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)` does not work.

Comment: I think this should help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548429/2836621